# Opening the browser through an Intent and Posting data for PayPal

Tags: android

I want to press an Android button and automatically direct the user to the PayPal site with all the relevant data POSTED along also.  Is this possible?

Comment: This provides an answer with actual working code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643385/start-the-android-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PayPal offers a URL where you can supply the data you want via a GET request (i.e., encoded form variables as part of the URL itself), then yes -- just convert the URL into a `Uri` via `Uri.parse()`, then call `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on that `Uri`.

If PayPal does not offer a URL with GET parameters to accomplish what you want, then no, it is not possible.

Comment: Actually it looks like they do support get...it didn't expect they would.

Comment: Hello Jax, did you achieve to do it at the end ?

Comment: Yes, I used GET instead of post - passing each of the button variables (the form fields from the button you copy from paypal) in the query string.