# Start the android browser

Tags: android

I need directions on how to start the android browser through code .
Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a fully blown browser try with :

```
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://Yoururl.com")));
```

Have a look to [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/intl/it/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) Intent.

If you want to simply display some HTML try using [WebView](http://developer.android.com/intl/it/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://yoururl.org/");
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. But from what I can see you'd either want a WebView or to be able to use an Intent to use the Browser itself.

Check out the documentation of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). There's also a blog post which gives you 4 ways of opening a web page in Android. I guess a commonly used method would be using **Intent.ACTION_VIEW**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://stackoverflow.com" );
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Here's a [blog post](http://mgmblog.com/2009/01/06/four-different-ways-of-opening-a-web-page-in-android/) explaining this