# How to call Default Browser in main activity?

Tags: android, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open a URL in Android’s web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)
>   [Start the android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643385/start-the-android-browser)

I check some reference I use below code to call Default Browser in main activity.

```
        Intent intent= new Intent();        
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");    
        Uri content_url = Uri.parse("www.baidu.com");   
        intent.setData(content_url);           
        intent.setClassName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.FMSActivity");   
        startActivity(intent);
```

And then modify xml:

```
               <intent-filter>
　　                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
　　                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
　　                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
　　                <data android:scheme="file" />
　　            </intent-filter>
```

But I get the Log error:

```
12-21 05:54:56.367: E/AndroidRuntime(277): at sz.zd.SzActivity.onCreate(SzActivity.java:19)
```

How to call Default Browser in main activity?

Comment: what is SzActivity.java:19 line in SzActivity activity?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Comment: The intent filter does not belong in your app (but rather the browser), unless you want your own app to respond to the intent in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by default? The one the user declared as default? If yes then this is the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
i.setData(Uri.parse(THE_URL));
startActivity(i);
```

You don't actually need to add intents to the application XML, that means an other thing. You might want to read through the docs to learn what intent-filters are for.