# how i can translate the username and password to browser on android

Tags: android, browser

now,I have a problem,please help me if you know,thanks!

I have a Activity to show my username and password,and it have a button that will jump         to browser of system to show a web page, how can i transfer my username and password to browser.

Comment: What does your mean? You want to access the page like `http://www.yoursite.com/?username=yourusername&password=yourpassword` ?

Comment: Hope the following provided links will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154862/opening-the-browser-through-an-intent-and-posting-data-for-paypal

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119827/how-can-i-open-android-browser-with-specified-post-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to pass uri in intent or so.

Hope the following provided links will help:

[Opening the browser through an Intent and Posting data for PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154862/opening-the-browser-through-an-intent-and-posting-data-for-paypal)

[How can I open android browser with specified POST parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119827/how-can-i-open-android-browser-with-specified-post-parameters)